# what is the difference between these two javascript codes? And is it possible to use somewhere second one?

Tags: javascript

im beginner in Javascript. First method  have learnt from tutorial. What is the difference between this and one below? And is it possible to use somewhere second one?

```
       function person (name, age){
        this.names = name;
        this.myage = age;
        this.yearsuntilretire = yearsleft
       }
        function yearsleft (){
            var numyears = 65 - this.age;
            return numyears;
        }

        var Vagif = new person ("Vagif Aghayev", 19);

        document.write (Vagif.yearsuntilretire);
```

---

Second code tried to write by myself

```
  function person (name, age, retire){

         this.names = name;
         this.myage = age;
         this.yearsleft = retire;

     }

     var Vagif = new person("Vagif Aghayev", 19, 65);


     document.write (Vagif.yearsleft-Vagif.myage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are practically doing the same thing but in different ways. By the way `this.age` from `yearsleft()` should be `this.myage`.

First piece of code contains two methods. First method is used as a constructor to asign values and properties to the future created object which you've done using the `new` keyword. In the second function `yearsleft()` you just make your calculus, the difference between two ages and return the result.

```js
function person(name, age) {
  this.names = name;
  this.myage = age;
  this.yearsuntilretire = yearsleft
}

function yearsleft() {
  var numyears = 65 - this.myage;
  return numyears;
}

var Vagif = new person("Vagif Aghayev", 19);

console.log(Vagif.yearsuntilretire());
```

In the second piece of code the things are done much easier, but you're practically making return the same thing as the first case:

```js
function person(name, age, retire) {

  this.names = name;
  this.myage = age;
  this.yearsleft = retire;

}

var Vagif = new person("Vagif Aghayev", 19, 65);


console.log(Vagif.yearsleft - Vagif.myage);
```

Regarding your last question: *And is it possible to use somewhere second one?*, yes, it is possible to use both of those codes, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
function person (name, age){
   this.names = name;
   this.myage = age;
   this.yearsuntilretire = yearsleft
}

function yearsleft (){
   var numyears = 65 - this.myaage;
   return numyears;
}

var Vagif = new person ("Vagif Aghayev", 19);

document.write (Vagif.yearsuntilretire);
```

you are using a function property to calculate and return the years until retire of the person. And here:

```
function person (name, age, retire){
    this.names = name;
    this.myage = age;
    this.yearsleft = retire;
}

var Vagif = new person("Vagif Aghayev", 19, 65);

document.write (Vagif.yearsleft-Vagif.myage);
```

you make this count directly in code, not in the person. That is the only difference.

I suggest you to read about class getters/setters (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions). This is a delightful way to deal with your years left.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calculating year left correctly. your code will always give year left for retirement as 65. which is not according to business logic.

instead you can use like this:

```
 function person (name, age, retire){
     this.names = name;
     this.myage = age;
     this.yearsleft = retire-age;

 }

 var Vagif = new person("Vagif Aghayev", 19, 65);


 document.write (Vagif.yearsleft-Vagif.myage);
```

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that "Vagif.yearsuntilretire" is not related to the object. Then you can simply use second approach. if its related to object then the first method approach will be good to use as it shows collective information of that object as you don't have to calculate again.